# Get X and Y pixel coordinates when iterating over HTML5 canvas getImageData

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am iterating over some image data pulled from a `canvas` like so:

```
var imageData = this.context.getImageData(0, 0, this.el.width, this.el.height);
var data = imageData.data;

for (var i = data.length; i >= 0; i -= 4) {
    if (data[i + 3] > 0) {
        data[i] = this.colour.R;
        data[i + 1] = this.colour.G;
        data[i + 2] = this.colour.B;
    }
}
```

How do I calculate the current X and Y pixel coordinates that I am at?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A Simple Arithmetic Sequence:

Divide the linear position by the width.  That's your Y-coordinate.  Multiply that Y-coordinate by the width, and subtract that value from the linear position.  The result is the X coordinate.

Also note, you will have to divide the linear position by 4 since it is RGBA.

Comment: Dude - thanks for that, I've been banging my head against a brick wall for a couple of hours with this, sorted now

Comment: Could you provide an example? I do not think I fully understand this sequence. Are the below answers correct by any chance? I am struggling to get the X and Y coordinates of a pixel. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think I just need to know what "linear position" means. Is that the position in the data array? Or pixel position which is the index/4 ??

Answer (score 43):

Corrected and tested version of code:

```
var x = (i / 4) % this.el.width;
var y = Math.floor((i / 4) / this.el.width);
```

Comment: Just to clarify this to future developers, width is the width of the canvas, not the length of the context's imageData.

Comment: Note that `this.el.width` can also be replaced with `imageData.width`.