# Inverse of Position to Index using Math.floor and modulo

Tags: javascript, html

I have seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20445915/3994249).

```
var x = (i / 4) % 320;
var y = Math.floor((i / 4) / 320);
```

This is how to get `x and y` when `i` is known. I want the reverse of this, so I want the `i` value of a given `x and y` coordinates according to formula above.

I have tried this:

```
let i = y * 4 * 320 + x * 4;
```

Comment: How exactly would you expect to mathematically inverse Math.floor?

Comment: @Taplar Math.ceil xd

Comment: The code posted is not even syntactically correct; there's a missing `)` somewhere.

Comment: I'm being serious.  Mathematically, considering all non integers, there are an infinite number of possibilities that `i` could be that would result in the same value for Math.floor.

Comment: @Taplar yes, basically it s a function which has multiple x for one y meaning it's not a function... Horizontal line criterion. I believe it 's called the injection rule which does not fit for Math.floor

Comment: Just to be sure: you have an array that you "handle" as a matrix, for which you already can get (x,y) position given the index "i". And now you want to calculate "i" from a given (x,y). Is that what you want?

Comment: yes array from `context.getImageData()` @Roimer

Comment: I tryed your code ´let i = y * 4 * 320 + x * 4;´ and it works both ways as long as ´i´ is a multiple of 4 (`i` is the 4th bit)

Comment: I was confused by x = 320 y = 180, which i is 724, I guess that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

x is "the same" number of y. You can take the i value by x value or by y value.

```
i === 4 * 320 * x; 


i === 4 * 320 * y;

let i = 4 * 320 * x;
let i = 4 * 320 * y;
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, OP is trying to get the _i-th_ "pixel" in a vector (linear array), given the (x, y) position in a 320xN array. You can see that in original code he uses "modulus" when calculating _x_ and "division + floor" when calculating _y_: you need both _x_ and _y_ to get the orginal value of _i_.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are processing an image. So what I would do is first find the offset of the current pixel `i` represents so you dont get partial values and then solve for `(x,y)` using a similar formula you are already using.

```
const w = 4; // rgba width in elements
const n = 320; // number of bytes per y. 80px * 4 = 320?
const j = i - (i % w); // start of current pixels data
const k = j % n; // x offset of current pixel data
const x = k / w; // scale by w, this will give us the actual pixel coordinate.
const y = (j - k) / n; // get actual y coord of pixel.
```

Since we are not doing any division that are not multiples, we will never have to use floor functions.

To solve for `i`, we reverse the process. This will give you an `i` that represents the start of the pixel.

```
const i = (y * n) + (x * w);
```

`n` is assumed to be bytes per scanline, and you are dealing with an 80px image. If this is not the case simply adjust `n` to be the `4 * imageWidth`.